# Извлечь массивы в которых есть нужный ключ в значении

Tags: python, json

```
{
  "result": {
    "list": [
      {
        "info": "Спорт",
        "county": "fr"
      },
      {
        "info": "Спорт",
        "country": "fr"
      },
      {
        "info": "Спорт",
        "country": "br"    
      },
      {
        "info": "Спорт",
        "country": "it"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Есть задача, массивы у которых есть значения с ключами "country": "it", и "country": "br" вывести в переменную удалив массивы у которых есть "country": "fr"

В результате нужно получить такой json

```
{
  "result": {
    "list": [
      {
        "info": "Спорт",
        "country": "br"    
      },
      {
        "info": "Спорт",
        "country": "it"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Пробовал использовать jq. Через него получается правильный результат, но через питон не могу понять как это сделать.
`.result.list[]? |select(.country == "it",.country=="br")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json
js = """{
  "result": {
    "list": [
      {
        "info": "Спорт",
        "country": "fr"
      },
      {
        "info": "Спорт",
        "country": "fr"
      },
      {
        "info": "Спорт",
        "country": "br"    
      },
      {
        "info": "Спорт",
        "country": "it"
      }
    ]
  }
}
"""
x = json.loads(js)
x['result']['list'] = list(filter(lambda y: y['country'] in ('it', 'br'), x['result']['list']))
js=json.dumps(x,indent=2,ensure_ascii=False)
print(js)
```

```
{
  "result": {
    "list": [
      {
        "info": "Спорт",
        "country": "br"
      },
      {
        "info": "Спорт",
        "country": "it"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: для загрузки json'а лучше использовать `json.loads`